# Jquery drag & delete confirmation popup implementation

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm new to Jquery and I would appreciate your help.

I have X list of items and a recycle bin. Idea is to drag one of the X list items and drop into the recycle bin.

When I drop it into the bin, I want to pop-up a delete confirmation window.

I have tried a lot of manuals, but none of them shows how to make this thing work.

Here's my code:

```
[Fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/KWdcU/175/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try in the drop function displaying a dialog with two buttons (confirm/cancel) and then attaching your $(ui.draggable).remove(); to an onClick

Comment: Thanks, but I can not get it to work. Could you please help me a bit with syntax?

Comment: Try adapting the example  [Jquery Dialog Modal Confirm Example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), it seems to be exactly what you want to do